# How to obtain list of tables names from a MySQL database in a C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

How to obtain list of tables names from a MySQL database in a C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

Here it is

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Tables where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Hope this helps everyone looking out for an answer. :)

Comment: Your question seems to ask how to find out the tables in a single DB, but your answer seems to provide how to find out the tables in a single installation (many DBs).

Answer (score 2):

see this link, its explain from the beginning of connect

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial139_Connecting-to-MySQL-with-Csharp-and-ODBC.html

u need to run `"show tables"`

```
private void btnListTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

      if (OdbcCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)

      {

            // Execute the SHOW TABLES query on the MySQL database

            OdbcCom = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("SHOW TABLES", OdbcCon);

            OdbcDR = OdbcCom.ExecuteReader();

            txtLog.AppendText("Tables inside " + txtDatabase.Text + ":\r\n");

            // Loop through the list of tables and display each one

            while (OdbcDR.Read())

            {

                  txtLog.AppendText(">> " + OdbcDR[0] + "\r\n");

            }

      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Haim Evgi for the quick reply. But I got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Is [it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-tables.html) useful? I think you may query MySql db from C# normally with this syntax, then consume the results.

Comment: Thanks Renato Gama for the quick reply. But I got the solution :)